# Why is Eclipse PDE Launch Configuration is building all projects

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, launch-configuration

I have created a launch configuration to run an executable file. When I run the configuration, it builds all projects in the workspace before running the actual tool to launch the file.

Anyone has any idea why it builds all projects, I want to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

1. Open the configuration dialog, and go to your configuration.
2. Go to the "Build" tab
3. Deselect "Build before launch", or choose whatever suits your needs.